# PHP: Generate random alphanumeric string that is unique to values in phpmyadmin table

Tags: php, string, random, unique, alphanumeric

I need to generate a random alphanumeric string that is unique to all values in a specific column in one of my tables in phpmyadmin. Also, I need it to be 20 characters long. There are many questions like this already posted but I didn't see any that needed a string unique to a column in phpmyadmin.

So how would I do this in php?

Comment: Generate a random string using any of the methods in the related questions, check whether it's already in use in the column. Repeat until you get one that's not in use.

Comment: AFAIK, Phpmyadmin is not a database engine. If you want to generate random strings with a certain character length, there is a lot of information about this online. You would have to check each time to see if that value is unique in the column.

Answer (score 5):

Something like this:

```
function isToken($token)
{
    if (isset($token) && $token) {

        //verification values in BD
        $query = "SELECT id FROM table WHERE token='$token'";
        $sql = mysql_query($query);
        if (mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

function generateUniqueToken($number)
{
    $arr = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f',
                 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l',
                 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'r', 's',
                 't', 'u', 'v', 'x', 'y', 'z',
                 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F',
                 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L',
                 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'R', 'S',
                 'T', 'U', 'V', 'X', 'Y', 'Z',
                 '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6',
                 '7', '8', '9', '0');
    $token = "";
    for ($i = 0; $i < $number; $i++) {
        $index = rand(0, count($arr) - 1);
        $token .= $arr[$index];
    }

    if (isToken($token)) {
        return generateUniqueToken($number);
    } else {
        return $token;
    }
}


$uniqueToken = generateUniqueToken(20);
```

Comment: return false; // <-- forgot semi-colon

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to get unique random in a MySQL table automatically. You must create a unique random text in PHP and find it in the MySQL table, and if it exists generate it again.

```
protected function generateToken($length=6){
    return substr(str_shuffle('abcdefghijklmnpqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890'),rand(0,60-$length),$length);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I could make it super simple:

```
echo md5(time());
```